# .net Dynamic String in If Condition

Tags: .net, json

I want to use *dynamic string* in if condition but the code gets exception.

```
   var params = {};
   params.windowKey = "File";
```

This params variable pass another function to later use like this : *escape(Ext.encode(params))*

The below code has the problem.

```
  dynamic allFields = JSON.Deserialize(Ext.Net.Utilities.EscapeUtils.Unescape(jsonVariable));

  if (allFields.windowKey.Value = "File")
  {
      UploadDocument(data.FileName, fileBytes, allFields.sqId);
  }
  else if (allFields.windowKey.Value = "Csv")
  {
      UploadCSV(sender, data);
  }
```

It gets exception when the code comes to the if blok.
How can i control the value?

Comment: Which exception are you getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `.Value` to retrieve the value. Think of dynamic as a string-based dictionary.

```cs
var json = @"{""windowKey"": ""File""}";
dynamic allFields = //Deserialize(json);

//access the properties by their name
Console.WriteLine(allFields.windowKey); //prints: File
Console.WriteLine(allFields["windowKey"]); //prints: File

if (allFields.windowKey == "File") {
    //do something
}
```